# Set minimum value or column randomly where minimum values are same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with minimum value. Here in the below table, d1, d2, d3 values are minimum values. When SQL min() or least() functions are used, it will always result `left side first` (perhaps I am wrong) means `d1` column here.

> My question is : Is there any possibility to set `least value or least column` randomly among d1, d2 or d3. I want to say here, for every execution time, least_column will be changed where values are same.

Table `formal`

```
id  date                    name    d1  d2  d3  d4  least_value     least_column
1   2017-02-10T09:00:00Z    bimal   1   1   1   4   1               d1
```

```
select f.*,
       (case ff.least_column
             when 'd1' then d1
             when 'd2' then d2
             when 'd3' then d3
             when 'd4' then d4
        end) as least_value,
        ff.least_column
from formal f cross join
     (select least(d1, d2, d3, d4) as least_value,
             (case least(d1, d2, d3, d4)
                   when d1 then 'd1'
                   when d2 then 'd2'
                   when d3 then 'd3'
                   when d4 then 'd4'
              end) as least_column
      from formal
     ) ff;
```

[SQL Fidle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f914b9/3)

Comment: I don't follow your question.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to set `d2` or `d3` column  as `least_column` instead `d1` column. Is it possible to set?

Comment: It is the order of the fields within the case expression's conditions that determines which field name is returned as the least value. If you can generate the sql dynamically where the order of the fields in the case is randomized, then you can randomize the field name received as an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relying on a small row structure which limits the ability to randomize. I suggest you "unpivot" the data to produce more rows and then you can get a more random result. Note `order by rand()` is fine for small result sets/tables but not for large sets.

You will need to visit this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3feb2f/2) and click run to see any "randomness"

```
CREATE TABLE formal
    (`id` int, `date` datetime, `name` varchar(5), `d1` int, `d2` int, `d3` int, `d4` int)
;

INSERT INTO formal
    (`id`, `date`, `name`, `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-02-10 09:00:00', 'bimal', 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
*
from (
      select id, date, name, d1 colvalue, 'd1' colsource from formal union all
      select id, date, name, d2         , 'd2'           from formal union all
      select id, date, name, d3         , 'd3'           from formal union all
      select id, date, name, d4         , 'd4'           from formal
    ) p
inner join (
        select id, least(d1, d2, d3, d4) as least_value from formal
      ) lv on p.id = lv.id
where colvalue = least_value # correction here
order by rand()
limit 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3feb2f/2/0)**:

```
| id |                 date |  name | colvalue | colsource | id | least_value |
|----|----------------------|-------|----------|-----------|----|-------------|
|  1 | 2017-02-10T09:00:00Z | bimal |        1 |        d2 |  1 |           1 |
```

For a multi-row result, one per id:

```
select
    *
from (
      select
            p.*
          , lv.least_value
          , @row_num :=IF( @prev = p.id, @row_num + 1, 1)AS RowNumber
          , @prev := p.id
      from (
            select id, date, name, d1 colvalue, 'd1' colsource from formal union all
            select id, date, name, d2         , 'd2'           from formal union all
            select id, date, name, d3         , 'd3'           from formal union all
            select id, date, name, d4         , 'd4'           from formal
          ) p
      inner join (
              select id, least(d1, d2, d3, d4) as least_value from formal
            ) lv on p.id = lv.id
      cross join (
          select @row_num := 0, @prev := null
          ) vars
      where colvalue = colvalue
      order by p.id, rand()
    ) d
where rowNumber = 1
;
```

**result**

```
| id |                 date |  name | colvalue | colsource | least_value | RowNumber | @prev := p.id |
|----|----------------------|-------|----------|-----------|-------------|-----------|---------------|
|  3 | 2017-02-10T09:00:00Z | suman |        1 |        d3 |           1 |         1 |             3 |
|  1 | 2017-02-10T09:00:00Z | bimal |        1 |        d1 |           1 |         1 |             1 |
|  2 | 2017-02-10T09:00:00Z |  amal |        1 |        d2 |           1 |         1 |             2 |
```

see [this revised sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d8a89/5)

Comment: Will you plz check the sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/628603/1.    I want to get the table as  `id`,  `date`, `name`,  `d1`, `d2` , `d3`, `d4`, `colvalue`, `colsource`, `id`, `least_value`. I want to show all the names. Plz help

Comment: your comment makes no sense, every item of information you have made available to me is in that sqlfidde. are you asking "how do I get one row for each id?" (That would be a new question imho.) I am getting too tired and need to stop.

Comment: Sorry.  in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d8a89/1    How will get all the names? It means three row. I mean 3 ids or 3 row id wise. Again sorry for earlier.

Comment: geni has granted wish 1

Comment: Thank You so much. I am also up voting you.